# How display node author roles at node.html.twig

Tags: theming, nodes

My user case is:

Extlink module can add exception classes to avoid processing some links.

I want some external url links on nodes whom author belongs to a special role (premium) can be mark with a class (for example with premium role name) to set an exception at external links module.

Well, at node twig template I can render node owner name, using this: {{ node.Owner.name.value }} but I don't know how render author roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get roles in twig using:

```
{%  for role in node.Owner.roles %}
    {{ role.entity.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update :**
If you want to use roles in classes i recommended you to use `clean_class` filter to get the clean css class from roles instead of the code you post in comment use this:

```
   {% set custom_classes = [] %}
    {% for role in node.Owner.roles %}
      {% set class_role = role.entity.label | clean_class %}
      {% set custom_classes = custom_classes | merge([class_role]) %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div {{ attributes.addClass(custom_classes) }}>
      {{ content }}
    </div>
```

Comment: Perfect, my code output is like:

` 

<div class="
      {%  for role in node.Owner.roles %}
        {{ role.entity.label }}
      {% endfor %}
      ">Test

      {{ content }}

    </div>

`